# Dont show the sum of values in bar chart in Power BI

Tags: bar-chart, powerbi

I have a table which has dates in **Date** and a number in **TCount**. I am creating bar chart with **TCount** on Y-Axis and **Dates** on X-Axis. Now in bar chart, Power BI is adding all the values in **TCount**. I have to drill down to show the breakup in terms of months. How can I stop the Power BI from summing the values in Column B? I just want to show the month level breakup. The values in TCount are not individual values. They show the current position in that month. For example, in January it is 59 and February its 53. So we went down by 6 in February.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, this is a column chart, not a bar chart. A bar chart has horizonal bars. The vertical things are called columns. (For those who find this nitpicking, there is a chart that combines columns with line, but there is no chart that combines bars with line charts, so the wording does matter.)

Note the date hierarchy in the Axis field well. Can you see that it has three levels, i.e. under date there is

- year
- quarter
- month

Click the "x" to delete the drill levels you don't want to see. So in your case, delete year and quarter and your viz will show months by default.

Then, again, if your data spreads over several years, the months will aggregate the values for all the Januaries and all the Februaries etc.

You will need to filter for a specific year, but you can use a slicer for that.

Comment: Thanks for the correction about the chart type. Your solution did not help me because the problem is my data. Secondly I have to show the year and month. So when I keep only month, it starts aggregating the same months (e.g. Jan 2018 and Jan 2019). I have disabled the drill down by selecting "Date" instead of "Date Hierarchy". It has solved my problem temporarily. I will see how can I change the data. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good question! Good answer! But not upvotes? Why? Power BI needs more attention on SO. And also, arguably, more UPvotes!